# PHP-CGI pipe info

Tags: php, http-protocols

When I get in my server a HTTP request I get somthing like this:

```
 GET /my/page/home.php?arg1=1&arg2=2 HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomainname.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
```

What I want to know is how is the best way to pass all this info to PHP-CGI in a similar way apache2 does?
This is my home.php file.

```
<?php
echo "Hello World\nGET:\n";
print_r($_GET);
echo "\n\nPOST:\n";
print_r($_POST);
echo "\n\nSERVER:\n";
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: something like `file_get_contents("php://input");` ? or `apache_getenv()`

Comment: Apache2 uses environment variables to pass these values to php-cgi.

Comment: Is there any tutorial or PHP documentation? What if I want to develop my own socket server?